# how to get csrf_field in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

how to put a `{!! csrf_field() !!}` for a form inside vue component in VueJs framework,
I want something like this but in vue component

```
 <form id="login_success" @submit.prevent="phoneLogin">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input id="csrf" type="hidden" name="csrf" />
    <input id="code" type="hidden" name="code" />
 </form>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Laravel to serve the app?

Comment: thank you, I use Laravel for API, I get csrf_field from another laravel project and in this form I paste tha value of it like this 
`<input typye="hidden" value="<MY_CSRF_FIELD>" name="_token">` and it is solved

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Laravel with Vuejs, and not a full Single page application, add the token in the head and do the following in js. The technique relies on you using axios

```
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Laravel comes with a [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/d53539b47b6d2a20d0c3d3257ad801bc72547c9d/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js#L27-L39), which does this automatically

Comment: thank you, fixed my problem, I get csrf_field from another laravel project and in this form I paste tha value of it like this 
`<input typye="hidden" value="<MY_CSRF_FIELD>" name="_token">` and it is solved